# Java - Calculating Pi

Tags: java, pi

I've been wanting to calculate pi with the Gregory-Leibniz series, and there's something wrong with it. I'm a bit of a starter to Java, so this may not be a hard question to answer. I don't know what's going on, so can somebody help me please?

Code so far:

```
package com.waitdev.pi;

public class Pi {

    static int pi = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++) {

            if (isOdd(i)) {
                pi = pi+(4/((i*2)-1));
                // System.out.println(i);
            } else {
                pi = pi-(4/(i*2)-1);
                // System.out.println(i);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(pi);
    }

    private static boolean isOdd(int n) {
        if (n % 2 == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

FYI: The output for this is 28.

Thanks.

Comment: This is more a math question than a programming question.

Comment: How do you intend to write pi into an integer?

Comment: @Mr.M You're right, I'll try a different type. Thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: I didn't know that technique, but it's a slow one! The second decimal is guaranteed only from the 1256 iteration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: an `int` is an integer, whole number. you want to change it to:

`static double pi = 0;`

Otherwise the answer always gets rounded down to a whole number.

Secondly, you are missing parenthesis in your else statement:

```
} else {
    pi = pi-(4/((i*2)-1));
}
```

If you want to be completely safe, change your integers in the if and else clause to doubles:

```
            if (isOdd(i)) {
                pi = pi+(4.0/((i*2.0)-1.0));
                // System.out.println(i);
            } else {
                pi = pi-(4.0/((i*2.0)-1.0));
                // System.out.println(i);
            }
```

But that shouldn't be neccessary

Comment: yes it should. otherwise i = 0-2 will always be pi +/- 1 and 3+ will always be pi +/- 0. Though he only needs one .0, not all of them I guess.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a parenthesis in your `else` block, and you need to force float calculation by e.g writing 4.0 instead of 4.
It should read:

```
if (isOdd(i)) {
    pi = pi+(4.0/((i*2)-1));
    // System.out.println(i);
} else {
    pi = pi-(4.0/((i*2)-1));
    // System.out.println(i);
}
```

You also need to use a `float` or a `double` for `pi`.

Extra - as for your isOdd method, it could be simplified like:

```
private static boolean isOdd(int n) {
     return (n % 2 == 1)
}
```

But this does not influence the result.

Comment: I tried this, and the result is 3.0 now. It's an improvement, but not what I was hoping. Thanks though.

Comment: @Waitdev_ `4/((i*2)` still give you int value.because `int/int=int`

Comment: You might want to write `4.0` instead of 4 - that'll force the usage of non-integers. Uptaded the answer.

Comment: Since using Gregory-Leibniz series could lead to millions of iterations, *odness* can be established a tad faster by using `(i & 0x01) > 0`